# how to save key pressed in text file

Tags: c++

I try to make key logger by C++ and I want to save any key pressed in text file.
I can know what key is pressed but I have problem when the program want to save the key it just save last key pressed. How can I solve this problem 
this is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    system("color 09");
    int asciiValue;
    char key;
    cout << "enter any key " << endl << endl;
    cout << "press ESC to exit.." << endl << endl;
    while (1)
    {
        key = _getch();

        asciiValue = key;

        if (asciiValue == 27)
        {
            system("cls");
            system("color 8a");
            cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\tCLOSE" << endl << endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            exit(1);
        }


        cout << "key pressed is : \" " << key << " \"" << "his Value = " << asciiValue << endl << endl;

        ofstream o("keylogger.txt");
        o << key;
        }


    cin.ignore(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Opening the `ofstream o` as you do reopens the file in every loop iteration, and clears its content before writing.   Either open the file before the loop, or read the documentation for `ofstream` to work out how to open a file in append mode (which won't clear the content, but will instead append to the file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new file on each iteration.
Just put the line:

```
ofstream o("keylogger.txt");
```

before the while loop

Comment: it well not be do if i put it out while loop because it can't go out while loop

Comment: @IbrahimTEslim I don't get why you can't: `ofstream o("keylogger.txt"); while(cond){ ... } return 0;`

Comment: what is while(cond) mean??

Comment: @IbrahimTEslim in your case you are using `1`, it's ok for testing, but in actual case you may need a condition `bool cond` to break the while loop and finish the program. Just a detail, and maybe offtopic...